# How to handle Pageload and display result in source tab using Selenium

Tags: selenium

Hi I need to implement a script that should capture all the object properties in a screen,
  and prepare an xml for this i used javascript and jQuery.

Coming to my problem is if I click any submit button / link the page is moved to another 
  page i lost the previous page information, i am thinking to solve this using Selenium IDE
  can any one please help me on this and i want to get the result in value field in the source
  tab.

REQUIRED FORMAT in Source Tab

```
<tr>
   <td>Testcase Name/ script Name</td>
   <td>Method Name</td>
   <td> XML as String </td>
</tr>
```

How can I insert my customize row in selenium IDE through javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do with IDE is limited and it's not possible to do what you want using javascript.

I don't see IDE loosing its information when you move to other pages.